# Vue Router passing props to dynamic routes, unclear documentation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a `ProjectCard` component which, among other things, links to a specific `ProjectPage` component. The ProjectPage is going to have a bunch of different paragraphs, pictures and so on, not wholly relevant for my question.

How do I pass on props to a `ProjectPage`? The [Vue Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode) portion on *Boolean Mode* is incredibly vague and doesn't really tell me anything useful.

My Router `index.js` file has the prop decoupling that they mention in the docs

```js
import ProjectPage from "@/views/ProjectPage.vue"

const routes = [
    {
        path: "projects/:id",
        component: ProjectPage,
        props: true
    }
```

To test things out, I made the `ProjectPage.vue` component look like this

```html
<template>
    <div>Static text, followed by {{ testString }}</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ProjectPage",
        props: {
            testString: String
        }
    };
</script>
```

And I tried passing on a test string to it from my `ProjectCard` component like this:

```html
<template>
    <router-link class="project-link" :to="{ path: `projects/${url}`, params: { testString: 'a dynamic string' } }" exact>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ProjectCard",
        props: {
            url: String
        }
    };
</script>
```

This will correctly take me to the specified route, eg `projects/table`. However, the `{{ testString }}` doesn't render and I can only see the `Static text, followed by a` portion of the component. There's no errors or warnings in the console.

Checking a `ProjectCard` component in the Vue debugger, the `testString` exists nested under `to/params/testString`:

[image: Vue Debugger for ProjectCard]

However, on any of the `ProjectPage` components, `testString` is `undefined`

[image: Vue Debugger for ProjectPage]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm a newbie and having the same problem; agree that the official Vue Router documentation is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about this

```js
import ProjectPage from "@/views/ProjectPage.vue"

const routes = [
    {
        name: 'Project',
        path: "projects/:id",
        component: ProjectPage,
        props: true
    }
```

and

```js
<template>
    <router-link class="project-link" :to="{ name: `Project`, params: { testString: 'a dynamic string' ,id: url} }" exact>
</template>
```

As the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort) said

> params are ignored if a path is provided, which is not the case for query, as shown in the example above.

```js
const userId = '123'
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId } }) // -> /user/123
router.push({ path: `/user/${userId}` }) // -> /user/123
// This will NOT work
router.push({ path: '/user', params: { userId } }) // -> /user
```

> The same rules apply for the `to` property of the `router-link` component.

Comment: I hadn't realized I can pass the id in the params, thank you for the doc link!