# Passing props through a router-link

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, router, vuejs3, vue-props

I'm new with Vue 3 router things, so really need help with it.
I'm trying to pass prop through the router link.

So, I have a component Post, where a prop post is an Object.

**Post.vue**

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Post',
  props: {
    post: {
      type: Object as PropType<Post>,
      required: true,
    },
  },
```

I have a component EditPostForm, where should be absolutely the same object as in the Post component.

**EditPostForm.vue**

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'EditPostForm',
  props: {
    post: {
      type: Object as PropType<Post>,
      required: true,
    },
  },
```

And that's the router link in the Post component.

**Post.vue**

```
<router-link
  class="..."
  :to="{
     path: '/post/edit',
     props: post,
     query: { post: post.id },
   }"
   >Edit
</router-link>
```

**router/index.ts**

```
{
    path: '/post/edit',
    name: 'Edit Post',
    component: EditPostForm,
    props: Object as PropType<Post>,
},
```

And an error I'm getting

**Error**

```
[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "post" 
  at <EditPostForm fullPath="/post/edit?post=3" hash="" query= {post: "3"}  ... > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, you cannot pass props directly using `<router-link>` , but you can set `vue-router` to pass the route `params` as `props` to the component:

```js
{
    path: '/post/edit/:prop1/:prop2/:prop3', // set your desired props as params in the url
    name: 'Edit Post',
    component: EditPostForm,
    props: true, // set props to true, this will pass the url params as props
},
```

Then, in your template, you can specify `params` property within `:to`:

```html
<router-link
  class="..."
  :to="{
     path: '/post/edit',
     params: post, // <-- changed 'props' to 'params'
     query: { post: post.id },
   }"
   >Edit
</router-link>
```

Passing props can also be done via `Object mode` or `Function mode`, [read more about them in the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode).

Object mode wouldn't be helpful, since that's mostly used for static props, but maybe you can use the Function mode if what I have provided above doesn't work for your use-case.

Comment: Didn`t help.
Getting how error:
```No match found for location with path "/post/edit/"```
and
```Path "/post/edit/" was passed with params but they will be ignored. Use a named route alongside params instead.```
But thanks for responding!

Comment: @kadeikin Did you set the path in router/index.ts to '/post/edit/:post'. Also, in your router-link above:
params should be {post} not post

Comment: @priosshrsth Yes, I did. ```path: '/post/edit/:post'``` and ```path: '/post/edit', params: { post },```

Comment: @kadeikin Did you also change set `props: true` in `router/index.ts`? In the router config, `props` is a Boolean, but you've set it to `Object as PropType<Post>`.

Comment: @tony19 Yes, I did

Comment: @kadeikin Can you create a reproduction in Codesandbox to help troubleshoot?

Comment: Please note this as well: "Note: params are ignored if a path is provided, which is not the case for query" [via](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#Navigate-to-a-different-location)

Answer (score 0):

### Use **[Provide/Inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject)** to pass data to any child component:

Quoted from Vue.js documentation:

> A parent component can serve as a dependency provider for all its descendants. Any component in the descendant tree, regardless of how deep it is, can inject dependencies provided by components up in its parent chain.

So in your case, If your code is such that *Post.vue* is the parent of *EditPostForm.vue*,(Or you can implement it to be) you can use **Provide/Inject**:
In your *Post.vue* instead of defining props, use **Provide**:

```
<script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          posts: {
            // some key:value pair of data
          },
        };
      },
      provide() {
        //sending data to any child component
        return {
          posts: this.posts,
        };
      },
    };
</script>
```

And in your *EditPostForm.vue*, use **inject** to retrieve data:

```
<script>
export default {
  inject: {
    //receiving data from parent component
    post: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```