# passing data between two components with router-link props

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I started learning Vue, and I wanted to pass data between component to another without using the parameter/query way and expose data in the URL,

I found an article online that suggested to pass data like the way below but unfortunately it's undefined in the second component! I mean the `user` variable is undefined!

comp1

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      Router linkoo
      <router-link to="/comp2" :props="{ user: user }">Go to Comp2</router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Comp1',
  data() {
    return {
      user: 'john'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

comp2

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>You're in comp2</div>
    <div @click="log">Click me</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Comp2',
  props: ['user'],
  methods: {
    log() {
      console.log(this.user)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Simple router setup:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    name: 'comp1',
    component: comp1,
    path: '/'
  },
  {
    name: 'comp2',
    component: comp2,
    path: '/comp2'
  }
]
```

passing the data from first component to second component correctly

Comment: router-link doesn't take `props`.  if you want to pass data using just Vue Router you need to use params and/or queries, which will be part of the URL.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891174).  There are other ways to pass data between components outside of Vue Router (Pinia or other global store, provide/inject, props/emits) that you can use instead.

Comment: Hi there! If you are just starting out with Vue, I'd suggest using Composition API, instead of the Options API you might find in a lot of articles. It's the direction Vue is moving into. Having said that, I would encourage you to go through the basics from their guide. Read through everything under the `Essentials` section. For your question in particular, try to understand https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics#passing-props